# Using a variable created in a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are two JavaScript variables in my `index.html` page. I want to use these two variables in control.js.

`index.html` has some jQuery script like below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// load select code from country.html
$('#selectCourse_country').load('country.html select', function() {
    // when country is selected
    $('#selectCourse_country select').change(function() {
        // get id
        var countryId = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
        // load select code from state.html by id
        $('#selectCourse_state').load('state.html #'+countryId,function(){
            $('#selectCourse_state select').change(function(){
                var stateId = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
               //alert(stateId);                    
            });
        });
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

I want to use value of variables `countryId` and `stateId` in `control.js`. How can I pass them from `index.html` to `control.js`.

Comment: Is control.js in another page, or the same one?

Comment: 1. save them on the DOM
2. save them on the DOM db

Comment: Couldn't you just load control.js right afterwards and store variables in a hidden dom with jquery?

Comment: Many html pages can load the same javascript file.  There are no javascript pages. The file contains the text of some code.  The variables for that code only exists on the browser, as initialized by the javascript code.  Shared data has to be requested with ajax, or be part of the HTML, or in a cookie or local database.

Comment: how about cookies? you can use jQuery.cookie. Can you post the control.js code where you are trying to use those vars?

Comment: Is there any way that you can make this more specific? Your question is really open-ended and it's hard to tell what you've tried and/or what kind of solution you would prefer. For example, you could: use global variables on the page; put the data into a cookie; put the data into URL params; retrieve the data from remote ajax end-points; store the data in `data-` attributes on elements in the page; use hidden fields...

Answer (score 2):

> Make a global container in your project which can contain any object. and those objects can be access globally in any js page of your application.

```
window.global ={country_ID : countryId , state_ID : stateId};
```

> Then use them in control.js like :

```
var contId =window.global.country_ID;
var statId =window.global.state_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery.cookie (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) the following should suit your needs.

To write the cookies...

```
$.cookie("countryId", countryId);
$.cookie("stateId", stateId);
```

and then in control.js you can get the values like this...

```
var countryId = $.cookie("countryId");
var stateId = $.cookie("stateId");
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery solution is good. This is a 
Use cookies.

for brevity I only coded for stateID

```
//Store cookie.
 var stateId = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
 document.cookie = "stateid="+ stateId;

//Get user cookie and match stateID
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';')
for (var i = 0 ; i< cookies.length;i++){
 if(cookies[i].match(/stateid/)){
 //Do stuff
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for you.

**Passing data from html to another js file using modernizer.**

```
//Load JS through Modernizer
Modernizr.load([
  // Functional polyfills
  {
    // This just has to be truthy
    test : Modernizr.websockets && window.JSON,
    // socket-io.js and json2.js

    // Arrays of resources to load.
    both : [ '/js/jquery.min.js', '/js/jquery-ui-min.js'],
    complete : function () {
        // Run this after everything in this group has downloaded
        // and executed, as well everything in all previous groups
        $('#selectCourse_country').load('country.html select', function() {
        // when country is selected
        $('#selectCourse_country select').change(function() {
        // get id
        var countryId = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
        // load select code from state.html by id
        $('#selectCourse_state').load('state.html #'+countryId,function(){
            $('#selectCourse_state select').change(function(){
            var stateId = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
               //alert(stateId);                    
            });
        });
        });
      });
    }
  },
  // Run your code afte you've already kicked off all the rest
  // of your app.
  // Pass variables to this js file
  '/js/control.js'
]);
```